# Selecting data frame rows based on list of names in 2nd table (names with backslash)

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem with extracting specific rows from data frame.

I have 2 tables:

Table 1:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 2 | B1 |
| 3 | A2 |
| 4 | A18 |
| 5 | A1\x3bA1 |
| 6 | B1\x3bA1 |
| 7 | C3 |
| 8 | C39 |

Table is imported from .txt file and let's notice, that in column "name" there are some values with backslash. And the backslash is always with x3b behind it, so it look like this: NAME\x3bNAME (these two names are sometimes same and sometimes different).

Then I have second table with just 1 column which contains list of "names" I want to extract from Table 1.

Table 2:

| name |
| --- |
| A1 |
| C3 |

I need to extract all rows with these names (A1, C3) including those, which have this name written before or after "\x3b".

So the result would be:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A1 |
| 5 | A1\x3bA1 |
| 6 | B1\x3bA1 |
| 7 | C3 |

When I tried to figure this out (for example with function `grep`) the result included also similar (but not same) names, which I didn´t want. For example: I want rows with name A1, but the result includes also  A18 (as it contains "A1" in it). The same with C3 and C39.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: If you have new information you should incorporate that into your original post. Also, please make sure you include a **complete set of reprex** for us to try, instead of adding bits here and there after one has answered your question. I have deleted my answer since it cannot answer your question accurately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df[grepl(paste(paste0(df2$name, "(?:\\D|$)"), collapse = "|"), df$name), ]
```

Output:

```
  id  name
1  1    A1
5  5 A1;A1
6  6 B1;A1
7  7    C3
```

`paste(paste0(df2$name, "(?:\\D|$)"), collapse = "|")` is a regex pattern which looks for any element of df2$name, followed by either a non-digit (e.g. a letter), or the end of a string.

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  name = c("A1", "B1", "A2", "A18", "A1\x3bA1", "B1\x3bA1", "C3", "C39")
)
df2 <- data.frame(
  name = c("A1", "C3")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a mether of define a proper regex.

But we must to note a point: if the .txt file contains this string **"B1\x3bA1"** (one backslash), the command read.csv() will translate it into **"B1\\x3bA1"** (two backslash)

So, assuming there are the files **"df1.csv"** and **"tbl2.csv"**, We can do the following:

```
df1 <- read.csv("df1.csv")
df1
  id      name
1  1        A1
2  2        B1
3  3        A2
4  4       A18
5  5 A1\\x3bA1
6  6 B1\\x3bA1
7  7        C3
8  8       C39

tbl2 <- read.csv("tbl2.csv")
tbl2
  name
1   A1
2   B1
3   C3
pattern <- paste("(^",tbl2$name,"$)|(^",tbl2$name,"\\\\x3b",tbl2$name,"$)",sep="")

ind_pattern <- as.vector(unlist(sapply(pattern,function(x)grep(x,df1$name))))
```

**ind_pattern** will contain the index of all observations in **df1** that matches with observations in **tbl2**

```
ind_pattern
```

will produce

```
1 5 2 7
```

and

```
df1[ind_pattern,]
```

produces

```
  id      name
1  1        A1
5  5 A1\\x3bA1
2  2        B1
7  7        C3
```